# how can i write this code with one function

Tags: javascript

how can i write this code with one function?

```js
function myFunction1() {
  document.querySelector("#demo").innerHTML = document.querySelector("#demo1").innerHTML;
}

function myFunction2() {
  document.querySelector("#demo").innerHTML = document.querySelector("#demo2").innerHTML;
}

function myFunction3() {
  document.querySelector("#demo").innerHTML = document.querySelector("#demo3").innerHTML;
}

function myFunction4() {
  document.querySelector("#demo").innerHTML = document.querySelector("#demo4").innerHTML;
}

function myFunction5() {
  document.querySelector("#demo").innerHTML = document.querySelector("#demo5").innerHTML;
}

function myFunction6() {
  document.querySelector("#demo").innerHTML = document.querySelector("#demo6").innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: Just pass the element that the function should work with into the function as an argument.

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: So, for what purpose you need this function?

Comment: Without more context (html, your underlying intention, ...) it is pretty difficult to come up with sensible advice.

Answer (score 0):

Use a parameter on the function: (i've named it `n`, but you can name it something else if that sounds better to you)

```js
function myFunction(n) {
  document.querySelector("#demo").innerHTML = document.querySelector("#demo" + n).innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: 2 problems with this. 1. If you set up the event handler the modern way (with `.addEventListener()`), then `n` will reference the event that triggered the function. 2. Your solution passes in a number to append to a string to form the element `id`, when really, you should just pass a reference to the element.

Comment: @ScottMarcus where are you seeing anything about event handlers?

Comment: I'm not, but to allow for the possibility of using them, you need to account for the `event` argument.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Your logic to have the parameters as `(event, someArg)` doesn't make sense, because if you're making this into something that you can all like `.addEventListener(myFunction)` then there isn't a way (without some buffoonery) to get `someArg` passed as an argument. Any time you call `myFunction`, you'd need to pass in the event manually, like you have in your answer. For example, `.aEL((e) => myFunction(e, 1))`. Or in other contexts, explicitly pass null/undefined `myFunction(null, 1)`. If this were to be an event listener, you'd call it like `.aEL(() => myFunction(1))`

Comment: I'm not sure that simply having an event handler wrap a function call with an argument is bafoonery since it's a very common paradigm for any language where functions are first-class entities. Your explanation and sample aren't really needed since that's what I have in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it:

```js
function copyInnerHTML(sourceId, targetId = "#demo") {
  document.querySelector( targetId ).innerHTML = document.querySelector(sourceId).innerHTML;
}

copyInnerHTML("#demo1"); // This will copy innerHTML from #demo1 to #demo
copyInnerHTML("#demo2"); // This will copy innerHTML from #demo2 to #demo
copyInnerHTML("#demo3"); // This will copy innerHTML from #demo3 to #demo
copyInnerHTML("#demo4"); // This will copy innerHTML from #demo4 to #demo
copyInnerHTML("#demo5"); // This will copy innerHTML from #demo5 to #demo
copyInnerHTML("#demo6"); // This will copy innerHTML from #demo6 to #demo
```

```html
<!-- Source elements -->
<div id="demo1">Source Content 1</div>
<div id="demo2">Source Content 2</div>
<div id="demo3">Source Content 3</div>
<div id="demo4">Source Content 4</div>
<div id="demo5">Source Content 5</div>
<div id="demo6">Source Content 6</div>

<!-- Target element -->
<div id="demo">Target Content</div>
```

Making the target ID a parameter would indeed enhance the flexibility and reusability of the function.

Comment: You've supplied your answer as a code snippet, but that snippet can't be executed because you haven't added any HTML elements nor referenced them in your JS.

Comment: Might as well make the target ID (`#demo`) a parameter as well, makes it more dynamic

Answer (score -1):

Just pass the element that the function should work with into the function as an argument.

```js
// Get your static DOM references just once, rather
// than every time the function runs
const demo = document.querySelector("#demo");
const data = document.querySelector(".data");

// Function is set up to accomodate 2 arguments
// to be passed in. The event argument is automatically
// passed in when the function is registered as an
// event handler with .addEventListener(). The second
// argument will reference whatever element is passed
// for the second parameter.
function myFunction(event, element) {
  demo.innerHTML = element.innerHTML;
}

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(event){
  // Invoke the handler and pass appropriate references
  myFunction(event, data);
});
```

```html
<div id="demo"><b>Sample Text</b></div>
<div class="data"><i>Some other text</i></div>

<button type="">Go!</button>
```

Comment: "The event argument is automatically passed in when the function is registered as an event handler with .addEventListener()." I don't understand. Wouldn't this only be the case if this function itself was passed as the listener callback? When it's called inside a handler function, it acts like any other function called within a function.

Comment: @DarrylNoakes But, if it's called in response to an event, you need to pass along that event so it can be used. If you look at my answer, you'll see that I've accounted for it.

Comment: If you're attaching event listeners to multiple elements, then yes, having the event could be useful; but only if the function actually uses it. In your example, you provide no reason for `myFunction` to take the event; it never uses it, and it could simply be not passed in. It would make sense if `myFunction` used the event target to determine where to get the data from, but it doesn't and I don't see an explanation that it could.

Comment: With event delegation, there is one listener; the pattern I normally use is to get a reference to the element in that top-level handler and pass that reference to any sub-functions as needed. Or to get the values of certain data attributes and just pass those. I prefer the handler to manage the event, and any sub-functions get passed what they need; they shouldn't have to operate on raw events.

Answer (score -1):

You could try adding the function to the `window` object dynamically.

```js
const sleep = async (ms) => new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, ms));

Array.from({ length: 6 }, (_, index) => {
  const globalFunctionName = `myFunction${index + 1}`;
  window[globalFunctionName] = () => {
    const sourceSelector = `#demo${index + 1}`;
    document.querySelector('#demo').innerHTML = document.querySelector(sourceSelector).innerHTML;
  }
});

(async () => {
  myFunction1();
  await sleep(1000);
  myFunction2();
  await sleep(1000);
  myFunction3();
  await sleep(1000);
  myFunction4();
  await sleep(1000);
  myFunction5();
  await sleep(1000);
  myFunction6();
  await sleep(1000);
})();
```

```css
.hidden { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>

<div id="demo1" class="hidden">Demo 1</div>
<div id="demo2" class="hidden">Demo 2</div>
<div id="demo3" class="hidden">Demo 3</div>
<div id="demo4" class="hidden">Demo 4</div>
<div id="demo5" class="hidden">Demo 5</div>
<div id="demo6" class="hidden">Demo 6</div>
```

A better way would be to pass the selector:

```js
const sleep = async (ms) => new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, ms));

const myFunction = (sourceSelector) => {
  document.querySelector('#demo').innerHTML = document.querySelector(sourceSelector).innerHTML;
};

(async () => {
  myFunction('#demo1');
  await sleep(1000);
  myFunction('#demo2');
  await sleep(1000);
  myFunction('#demo3');
  await sleep(1000);
  myFunction('#demo4');
  await sleep(1000);
  myFunction('#demo5');
  await sleep(1000);
  myFunction('#demo6');
  await sleep(1000);
})();
```

```css
.hidden { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>

<div id="demo1" class="hidden">Demo 1</div>
<div id="demo2" class="hidden">Demo 2</div>
<div id="demo3" class="hidden">Demo 3</div>
<div id="demo4" class="hidden">Demo 4</div>
<div id="demo5" class="hidden">Demo 5</div>
<div id="demo6" class="hidden">Demo 6</div>
```

Alternatively,

```js
(async () => {
  for (let i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
    myFunction(`#demo${i}`);
    await sleep(1000);
  }
})();
```

Comment: You've taken simple, yet redundant, code and made it quite a bit more complex than it need be. All that is required is to have the function take an argument.

Comment: @ScottMarcus which is what I suggested at the bottom. I was demonstrating the ability to add named functions to the `window`.